# A verb for putting the results of two different studies to get an overall conclusion?

Tags: word-request

> In the end of my research I will ______ the results of these two
>   different studies to get a final conclusion.
>
> I will ______ the result with the result of another study and get an
>   overall conclusion.

I am looking for a verb for putting the results of two different studies together in order to get an overall conclusion? I thought of *assemble* and *combine*, but I am not sure about them. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

*I will **consolidate** the results of these two different studies to get a final conclusion*

> **consolidate** ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/consolidate))
>    *to bring together (separate parts) into a single or unified whole; unite; combine*

But see [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20consolidated%20study%2Ca%20combined%20study&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20consolidated%20study%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20combined%20study%3B%2Cc0) showing that in academic contexts, such research is more likely to be called a ***combined study*** than a ***consolidated study***.

Answer (score 1):

The verb [**to synthesize**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/synthesize) is commonly used to describe this, [especially in academia](https://msu.edu/~jdowell/135/Synthesis.html).

> I will **synthesize** the two different studies to *draw* a final conclusion.

Comment: But, it is not the "two different studies" which are synthesized: it is the final conclusion which is synthesized from those constituents.